# Create Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory as a Singleton class

Tags: c#, singleton

Im trying to use **Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory** as singleton class in Asp.net MVC 5.

Problem is with each call the Instance Variable returns null and class reinstantiating it

self.(old value of Cache will be deleted)

this is my cache class :

```
public class CacheManagerHelper<TItem>
    {

  private static CacheManagerHelper<TItem> instance;
        private static MemoryCache memoryCache;
        private static object syncRoot = new();
        private CacheManagerHelper() { }


        public static CacheManagerHelper<TItem> Instance
        {
            get
            {
                        if (instance == null)
                        {

                            instance = new CacheManagerHelper<TItem>();
                            memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions()
                            {
                            });
                        }

                return instance;
            }
        }


        
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim> _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim>();

        public async Task<TItem> GetOrCreate(object key, Func<Task<TItem>> createItem)
        {
            TItem cacheEntry;

            if (!memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheEntry))
            {
                SemaphoreSlim mylock = _locks.GetOrAdd(key, k => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));

                await mylock.WaitAsync();
                try
                {
                    if (!memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheEntry))
                    {
                        cacheEntry = await createItem();
                        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                   .SetPriority(Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove)
                   .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(24))
                   .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(48));


                        memoryCache.Set(key, cacheEntry);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    mylock.Release();
                }
            }
            return cacheEntry;
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(memoryCache.Get(key), typeof(T));
        }

        public void RemoveCache(string key)
        {
            memoryCache.Remove(key);
        }

        public static void ClearAllCacheObject()
        {
            IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(enumerator.Key.ToString());

        }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not use Dependency Injection? If you call [.AddMemoryCache()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.memorycacheservicecollectionextensions.addmemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), the extension method will register MemoryCache class as a Singleton. Then, you just need to ask for a MemoryCache instance in each class constructor you need to use it. Then you can create a helper class for your extension methods.

Comment: @TiagoRios Sadly Im Using mvc 5 before .net core and trying to avoid other app like autofac and ninject.